# setup.py install_requires not installing sqlalchemy wheel

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, setuptools, setup.py

I'm following [this](https://packaging.python.org/distributing/#requirements-for-packaging-and-distributing) guide to create a setup.py

Doing this I used install requires to specify sqlalchemy like so:

```
install_requires=['sqlalchemy']
```

Now when I run the setup.py install I get the message that there is no C extension is installed and the python alternative will be used. Which implicates that the sqlalchemy code is downloaded as dist and compiled instead of being downloaded as a wheel. If the packages is installed via pip there is no error/warning and the c version of sqlalchemy is installed using a precompiled wheel.

Why is this and how do i get around it?